# Rust iter-map-collect pattern with lifetimes

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to implement a shortcut for `Vec.iter().map(...).collect()` pattern that I use pretty often. At first glance, it doesn't look difficult:

```
pub trait IterMap<T> {
    fn mapcollect<F, U>(&self, f: F) -> Vec<U>
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> U;
}

impl<T> IterMap<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn mapcollect<F, U>(&self, f: F) -> Vec<U>
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> U,
    {
        self.iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}
```

It works like a charm for simple cases:

```
let v = vec![5; 5];
let v_2 = v.mapcollect(|x| x * x);
```

However, if lifetimes are involved, it breaks:

```
let v: Vec<Vec<i32> = ...; // define 2D-vector here
let v_slice: Vec<&[i32]> = v.mapcollect(|x| x.as_slice());
```

The reason being that Rust is unable to link the lifetime of `v_slice` to the one of `v` through my `mapcollect()` abstraction.

Of course, I can implement another `mapcollect_with_lifetime(...)` with proper lifetime annotations, but this approach has several disadvantages. Is there a way to help Rust figure out the lifetimes automatically, as the original `iter().map(...).collect()` does?

Comment: I'm curious what are the disadvantages of writing the lifetimes? (ecxept for obviously having to write the lifetimes)

Comment: @cafce25. I wrongly assumed that the lifetime of `v_2` would also be bound to the lifetime of `v`, which is not what you want, of course. However, it doesn't seem to be the case after experimenting a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a second implementation at all, you can do this with a single, properly implemented trait and implementation. This is because adding the lifetimes to your implementation *is* how you help rust automatically figure this out for the caller.

```rust
pub trait IterMap<'a, T: 'a> {
    fn mapcollect<F, U>(&'a self, f: F) -> Vec<U>
    where
        F: Fn(&'a T) -> U,
        U: 'a;
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> IterMap<'a, T> for Vec<T> {
    fn mapcollect<F, U>(&'a self, f: F) -> Vec<U>
    where
        F: Fn(&'a T) -> U,
        U: 'a,
    {
        self.iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![5; 5];
    let v_2 = v.mapcollect(|x| x * x);

    let v: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6]];

    let v_slice: Vec<&[i32]> = v.mapcollect(|x| x.as_slice());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had in mind for the version-with-lifetimes implementation. My concern was that the lifetime of `v_2` would also be bound to the lifetime of `v`. However, I experimented a bit and this is not the case. Somehow Rust is capable of figuring out that it's not needed.

Comment: Well the bound `U: 'a` means `U` can't live *shorter* than `'a` it doesn't say it can't live longer, say until the end of the program.

Comment: @cafce25, now I'm confused even more. :) Doesn't it mean exactly the opposite for slices? I.e. a slice can't live _longer_ than the respective vector?

Comment: Yes, slices can't outlive what they borrow from, but you can't put that in a bound since bounds always mean that the bound to item can't live shorter than a lifetime. `x: 'a` reads as `x` lives at least as long as `'a`

Comment: That's no different from all the other kinds of bounds by the way `A: Trait` also means `A` does at least implement `Trait`, it's free to implement any other traits as well.